# JavaScript - how to use "self" from current JS Class

Tags: javascript

I tried to create this syntax for JavaScript:

```
var user = new Class({
    name: 'No name',
    sayHello: function () {
        console.log(self.name);
    }
});

user.sayHello();  // will print "undefined" because "self" isn't visible
```

And I created this implementation of `Class`:

```
function Class (_properties) {
    var self = this;

    // copy all properties and methods to this class
    for (var _property_name in _properties) {
        self[_property_name] = _properties[_property_name];
    }
}
```

But the problem is in `self` that I wish to use in each class. The `self.name` will be undefined because `self` is a `[Window object]`.

---

**Question**: how to modify my code to use `self` inside all functions in class instances? The `self` is needed to not drop context if the function will be called from external context.

**Expected result** (I mean that code above should be executed as code below):

```
function Class (_properties) {
    var self = this;

    // properties

    self.name = 'No name';

    // methods
    self.sayHello = function sayHello () {
        console.log(self.name);
    };
}

var user = new Class();
user.sayHello();
```

---

> > **The goal of my experiment** is to use `self` that always is reference to current object. Because sometimes when we use calls like this `$.get('...', function () { console.log(this); })` - `this` is set to **function local scope**. But I wish to use `self` *(magic property)* that always be a reference to **object of current class** *(scope of current class)*.

Comment: how about name it something else? I usually use `me = this;`

Comment: `Class` doesn't return anything. What do you expect `User` to be? Either way, in your example `self` is a *local variable* and doesn't conflict with the *global* `self` variable. Please provide a better explanation of your problem or update your code to better demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You probably want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y7n0ow5t/. Since `User` is a constructor function, you want `Class` to return a *function*.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, I missed `new` statement. I corrected my code.

Comment: @dfsq you used `this.name` in your example, but I wish yo use `self.name` instead, to  be sure that I execute code in this Class context.

Comment: @AntonDanilchenko You don't need any `self`. The context is going to be proper is you use constructor function properly like in my example (with `new` keyword).

Comment: I don't get it. What's the problem with using `this`?

Comment: This question should be closed as primarily opinion based. What the OP wants to do makes no sense, and there seem to be multiple opinions on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Downvoted question - a working convention already exists for this (problem) circumstance - it's setting `var self = this` whenever you need to get a reference to `this` that can be used in a different scope. There is no solution to your experiment.

Answer (score 5):

So I finally figured out that you are talking about the `self` variable in the `sayHello` method that is giving you problems.

You need to google `JavaScript scope this tutorial` - it's not the most intuitive concept, but once you get it, everything will make sense.

In the mean time, it's worth pointing out that `self` is not a reserved word in JavaScript and doesn't do anything special, but `this` is.

So what you want, is something like this:

```
function Class (_properties) {

    // copy all properties and methods to this class
    for (var _property_name in _properties) {
        this[_property_name] = _properties[_property_name];
    }
}

var User = new Class({
    name: 'No name',
    sayHello: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
var user1 = new User();
var user2 = new User();
```

The keyword `new` in front of the `Class()` function causes it to be executed as a constructor function meaning that, inside of the constructor function `this` will reference it's own scope.

Also, because the property `sayHello` is a function to be executed inside the scope that you created, you can use `this.name` - as `this` will refer to the scope that you created when you instantiated a `new Class`.

And just because this scope thing is no doubt confusing (don't worry, it probably will be for a while) - if you haven't created a scope (by using a constructor or object literal) you're working inside of the `global` scope which, in the case of the browser, is the `Window` object.

Comment: Sorry for my typos in original message. The goal of my experiment is to use `self` that always is linked to current object. Because sometimes when we use calls like this `$.get('...', function () { console.log(this); })` - and if I use `this` it show me `this` that set to unction scope. But I wish to use `self` (magic property) that always a link to a object of this class.

Comment: **EDITED ORIGINAL COMMENT** (this one's better): Very simply: you can't create a magic property `self` that always references the current object, regardless of scope. Scope is very important in JS - once you're in a different scope, the only way back to the original scope is to retain a reference to it (i.e. `var self = this`). Whatever you\re trying to do, it's a waste of time, use the convention of using `var self = this` at the time and place you need to.

Comment: var user1 = new User(); // TypeError: Class is not a constructor (evaluating 'new User()')

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never created an object:

```
var options = {
    name: 'No name',
    sayHello: function () {
        console.log(self.name);
    }
}
var user1 = new Class(options);
var user2 = new Class(options);
```

"this" refers to the object owner of the current function. In this case would be windows object. At least you construct an object from the function Class.

If you want to avoid someone overwrite a property of `Class.prototype` is necessary to use `hasOwnProperty` in your `for in`

Comment: Thats wrong. When calling a function with new this refers to a new created object. So he **does** create an object. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new): `The constructor function foo is called with the specified arguments and this bound to the newly created object`. The problem is that the function (`sayHello`) captures `self` before the constructor is executed. So `self` is undefined. Adams answer is correct.